# Is there any way to define a block of text other than the initial text as the intro text?

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, intro-text

On some articles, the best text to use as the intro text isn't necessarily the initial text in the article.

Is there any way to define an alternative block of text later in the document as the intro text e.g. by using some plugin syntax such as `{introtext}` and `{/introtext}` to define the block or by using some other method?

Comment: Have a look to the extension "Articles Anywhere" from  NoNumber, I recently use this to show the intro text of other articles inside a separate article.

Comment: Thanks @Tom, I checked it out but I don't think it will help in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something you can do by combining the available abilities in Joomla core, but there are certainly many other custom ways to achieve this.

Of course it depends on how you want to use this and what you want to achieve, which you haven't clearly specified.
Do you want to save this in the database? Simply show it on your blog layout? or in modules?

Some example ideas:

1. Using the core capabilities: You can always use the intro-text separation as whole autonomous text field, by entering there your desired intro text, which you later will keep hidden from the article layout.
2. You could use the meta description field in conjunction with some template overrides.
3. Or you can use a custom field to extend com_content and then again with template overrides, or a custom(ized) module.
4. Or as you said you can involve a custom plugin and make use of your plugin's syntax to mark your desired intro text inside the article and then have the plugin either inject it wherever you want in the article or even saving it in the database.

Comment: I am using RokSprocket Mosaic view and there is an option to use the meta description instead of the intro text. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andrew Eddie, and expanding on example 1 in @FFrewin's answer:

1. Write whatever intro text you like, inserting the "Read More" at the end of the intro text as usual.
2. In the article options, set Show Intro Text = Hide (see example below)

The intro text will now only be shown in category blogs etc and not shown at all when viewing the article.

Reference: http://eddify.me/posts/joomlas-hidden-feature-hiding-intro-text.html

[image]

Comment: Hi Neil - that's what I meant on my #1 suggestion above. Maybe not that obvious on my description - but I thought it was something you already knew so I only wanted to point/remind it to you.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense now but not for me at the time! Thanks, I'll leave this answer here to help spell this out to others who aren't aware of this feature yet.